# is there any function in Uploadify called after all the uploaded files are deleted?

Tags: jquery, uploadify

is there any function in Uploadify which is called after all the currently uploaded files are deleted?

Regards,
Balan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest pre built thing is `onAllComplete`, but it sounds like you want something different. What I would do is:

1. Define `var count = 0;` outside of any funciton / method
2. In your `onSelect` handler function (which is called for each file that gets selected):

`count++;`

1. In your `onCancel` handler (called for each file removed):

   count--;

   ```
   if(count < 1){
     //Do whatever you wanted, there are not more items in queue
   }
   ```

(sorry formatting this post had some issues for some reason)

Comment: Great.. i ve been using the same logic.. but instead of Select i addded the event in some other function.. thanks